# How can I include a python package with Hadoop streaming job?

Tags: python, hadoop

I am trying include a python package (NLTK) with a Hadoop streaming job, but am not sure how to do this without including every file manually via the CLI argument, "-file".

Edit: One solution would be to install this package on all the slaves, but I don't have that option currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would zip up the package into a `.tar.gz` or a `.zip` and pass the entire tarball or archive in a `-file` option to your hadoop command.  I've done this in the past with Perl but not Python.

That said, I would think this would still work for you if you use Python's `zipimport` at http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html, which allows you to import modules directly from a zip.

Answer (score 29):

Just came across this gem of a solution: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/

first create zip w/ the libraries desired

```
zip -r nltkandyaml.zip nltk yaml
mv ntlkandyaml.zip /path/to/where/your/mapper/will/be/nltkandyaml.mod
```

next, include via Hadoop stream "-file" argument:

```
hadoop -file nltkandyaml.zip
```

finally, load the libaries via python:

```
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltkandyaml.mod')
yaml = importer.load_module('yaml')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
```

Additionally, this page summarizes how to include a corpus: http://www.xcombinator.com/2009/11/18/how-to-use-cascading-with-hadoop-streaming/

download and unzip the wordnet corpus

```
cd wordnet
zip -r ../wordnet-flat.zip *
```

in python:

```
wn = WordNetCorpusReader(nltk.data.find('lib/wordnet-flat.zip'))
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds.  Good find.

Comment: I tried this solution with hadoop streaming and provided the nltk zip with the -file option, the zipimporter keeps complaining that it is not a zip file, any thoughts on this? My mapper seems to work on my local machine its just on hadoop streaming that is causing the problem

Comment: @viper, maybe try the following fixes: 1) re-zip file, but maybe with different zip program or on different OS; 2) make sure that your paths are correct -- i.e. is zipimporter just not finding file?; 3) check versions of zipimporter on cluster vs. local machine?  I *vaguely* remember having a similar error once, but don't recall what I did to fix.

Comment: @dolan I did try re-zipping the file on my local machine. I will try to do it on the cluster and try again.

Comment: I tried again and it worked this time. I was using classes, and I put the zipimporter load_module line inside the class
That could have been the issue

Comment: Is there something equivalent for reading tar.gz file? I think tar.gz is more common and it is the default version from Pypi.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. --- I haven't seen any mention of tgz support, but I haven't looked at docs in a while.

Comment: I faced the same challenge these days and I couldn't be successful despite many efforts. Downloaded NLTK has an __init__.py and many other modules (directory) and various python file (load, internals, compat, ...). When I use the zipimport and importer.load_module("nltk/__init__"), it returns many errors of not finding modules because inside __init__ model is calling many of other .py files inside the nltk folder. For instance one error is :  
tokenizer = importer.load_module("nltk/__init__")  
ImportError: No module named nltk.collocations. 
How should I address this?
@DolanAntenucci

Comment: @Reihan_amn -- I'm not too sure where you're running into issues. One thing that looks problematic is you're loading "nltk/__init__", whereas __init__ files/functions are automatically loaded on modules. You're probably best off posting a new Stack Overflow question, and just reference this original question, and describe in detail your code, etc.

Comment: @DolanAntenucci Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunaly, I cannot post a new question since I have some recenlty.
When I download NLTK folder from their website, it is a folder with many .py files and other folders like (tokenize, tag,..) My problem is that I can import this zip file but when I am want to load the module, I am not sure which of these .py files I should load.??!

Comment: Dolan Antenucci I just have one question here. Does the nltk package that I download (from http://www.nltk.org/data.html) need to have 2 subfolders of yaml and nltk?

Comment: @Reihan_amn -- you really need to just ask a new question on this site; you're going to have better luck debugging what you're doing wrong. You mentioned before that you can't?  I don't see why that would be, so you should contact the site moderators if so. Unfortunately, I haven't worked with installing modules like you're trying to do in a while, so don't remember the answer to your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You can use zip lib like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'nltkandyaml.mod')
import ntlk
import yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

**An example of loading external python package nltk**

refer to the answer
 [Running extrnal python lib like (NLTK) with hadoop streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167933/running-extrnal-python-lib-like-nltk-with-hadoop-streaming/32135850#32135850)
I followed following approach and ran the nltk package in with hadoop streaming successfully.

Assumption, you have already your package or (nltk in my case)in your system

first:

```
zip -r nltk.zip nltk
mv ntlk.zip /place/it/anywhere/you/like/nltk.mod
```

Why any where will work?

Ans :- Because we will provide path to this **.mod** zipped file through command line, we don't need to worry much about it.

second:
changes in your mapper or .py file

```
#Hadoop cannot unzip files by default thus you need to unzip it   
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')

#now import what ever you like from nltk
from nltk import tree
from nltk import load_parser
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.data.path += ["."]
```

third: 
command line argument to run map-reduce

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file /your/path/to/mapper/mapper.py \
-mapper '/usr/local/bin/python3.4 mapper.py' \
-file /your/path/to/reducer/reducer.py \
-reducer '/usr/local/bin/python3.4 reducer.py' \
-file /your/path/to/nltkzippedmodfile/nltk.mod \
-input /your/path/to/HDFS/input/check.txt -output /your/path/to/HDFS/output/
```

Thus, above step solved my problem and I think it should solve others as well.
cheers,

Comment: Why you moved it to nltk.mod? why didn't directly import it from nltk.zip?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using much more complex libs such as numpy、pandas, virtualenv is a better way.
You can add -archives to send the env to cluster.

Refer to the writing:
https://henning.kropponline.de/2014/07/18/virtualenv-hadoop-streaming/

**Updated**:

I tried above virtualenv in our online env, and find some problems.In the cluster，there is some errors like "Could not find platform independent libraries "。Then i tried the conda to create python env, it worked well.

If you are Chinese, you can look this:https://blog.csdn.net/Jsin31/article/details/53495423

If not, i can translate it briefly:

1. create an env by conda：

   `conda create -n test python=2.7.12 numpy pandas`
2. Go to the conda env path.You can find it by cmd:

   `conda env list`

   Then,you can pack it:

   `tar cf test.tar test`
3. submit the job through hadoop stream：

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-archives test.tar \
-input /user/testfiles \
-output /user/result \ 
-mapper "test.tar/test/bin/python mapper.py" \
-file mapper.py \
-reducer"test.tar/test/bin/python reducer.py" \
-file reducer.py
```