# Hadoop: How to include third party library in Python MapReduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing MapReduce job in Python, and want to use some third libraries like `chardet`.

I konw that we can use option `-libjars=...` to include them for java MapReduce.

But how to include third party libraries in Python MapReduce Job ?

Thank you!

Comment: use the `import` statement?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried that, but not work. And it shows `ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA`

Comment: perhaps if you posted some example code, the errors you're getting, and what you're doing to get them, we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved by `zipimport`.

Then I zip `chardet` to file `module.mod`, and used like this:

```
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('module.mod')
chardet = importer.load_module('chardet')
```

Add `-file module.mod` in hadoop streaming command.

Now `chardet` can be used in script.

More details shown in: [How can I include a python package with Hadoop streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job/6811772#6811772)