# how to use python sklearn package in hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, scikit-learn

Hi: currently im running jobs using hadoop streaming, in my mapper, i need to use sklearn package as part of my program, but unfortunately sklearn package is not installed in my hadoop cluster nodes. 
I googled this problem and found that i could ship the package along with my job files and use zipimport to import package from my .tar.gz, however, when I downloaded the source codes of sklearn from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.14.1 , and tried

```
python setup.py build --inplace
```

or use

```
python setup.py
```

and select inplace build in the interactive session, either way i can get a new build folder under my sklearn source code folder, then i tried to zip ~/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/sklearn/ into a .zip file and follow instructions here: 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html 
 or here: [How can I include a python package with Hadoop streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job)
 but i will get an error saying

```
"__check_build is not a folder"
```

then i checked my zip file and confirmed this is a folder. it seems that i didnt build sklearn package properly. So anyone can point me to right direction? Thanks!