# Running external python lib like (NLTK) with hadoop streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, nltk, hadoop-streaming

I tried using http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/

```
zip -r nltkandyaml.zip nltk yaml
mv ntlkandyaml.zip /path/to/where/your/mapper/will/be/nltkandyaml.mod

import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltkandyaml.mod')
yaml = importer.load_module('yaml')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
```

And the error I got is:

> job_201406080403_3863/attempt_201406080403_3863_m_000000_0/work/./app/mapper.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       import nltk ImportError: No module named nltk

Anybody who did face a similar problem, can you please put a exhaustive solution.

Thanks

Comment: Does every node on your cluster has the imported library?

Comment: What did you try to do in loading?  Share with us the details.

Comment: @SAM I think idea of hadoop streaming is that we need not to install it on any node. we can send it and should be able to import it

Comment: @La-comadreja I am trying nltk to load

Comment: @nit254 You want to run the program on each node without having the library? Then you should pack the library into your program somehow like a binary executable. Hadoop won't share imported libraries with data nodes, cause it's not aware of them.

Comment: @La-comadreja I added the error logs now

Comment: @SAM So you are saying i have to install nltk on all the nodes ?

Comment: Yes I believe you have!

Answer (score 0):

I followed following approach and ran the nltk package in with hadoop streaming successfully.

note: I had only used nltk package not yaml, so my answer will only focus on loading nltk package not yaml, but I believe it should work for your question as well.

Assumption, you have already nltk package installed in your system

first:

```
zip -r nltk.zip nltk
mv ntlk.zip /place/it/anywhere/you/like/nltk.mod
```

Why any where will work?

Ans :- Because we will provide path to this **.mod** zipped file through command line, we don't need to worry much about it.

second:
changes in your mapper or .py file

```
#Hadoop cannot unzip files by default thus you need to unzip it   
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')

#now import what ever you like from nltk
from nltk import tree
from nltk import load_parser
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.data.path += ["."]
```

third: and most the important one I guess you might be missing is

command line argument to run map-reduce

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file /your/path/to/mapper/mapper.py \
-mapper '/usr/local/bin/python3.4 mapper.py' \
-file /your/path/to/reducer/reducer.py \
-reducer '/usr/local/bin/python3.4 reducer.py' \
-file /your/path/to/nltkzippedmodfile/nltk.mod \
-input /your/path/to/HDFS/input/check.txt -output /your/path/to/HDFS/output/
```

Thus, above step solved my problem and I think it should solve others as well.
cheers,