# Failed to include a third party python package with Hadoop streaming job

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I would like to include a third party python library when running Hadoop streaming job.

I followed the suggestions in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job) but it doesn't seem to work.

I submitted a command like this:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar \
-input $hdfs_input_file \
-output $hdfs_output_file \
-mapper $mapper_file \
-combiner $reducer_file  \
-reducer $reducer_file  \
-file $mapper_file \
-file $reducer_file \
-file $packaged_file
```

The $packaged_file is a packaged file that contains the third party library.

My script failed at this line (in $mapper_file):

```
xyz = importer.load_module('library_name')
```

The error message is

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

However, the above line of code run well in ipython.  I could even run the following line in ipython

```
xyz.method_foo()
```

Any suggestions on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is "library_name" installed in all the nodes of your cluster?

Comment: I want to pass the library by --file so that I don't need to install the library whenever a new computing node is added.