# Geos, Shapely and Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, geospatial, hadoop-streaming, shapely, geos

I'm trying to run a Hadoop streaming job to process geospatial data. To that end, I'm using [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) functions which require [libgeos](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos).

However, the job fails because libgeos is not installed on the cluster.

Is there a way to ship libgeos to the cluster and have Shapely read `.so` files from the directory (maybe by `-archives` or `-files`)?

**Example of commands run**

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -D    stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 -D mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,1 -archives hdfs://namenode:port/user/anaconda.zip#anaconda -files /some/other/stuff -input /path/to/input -output /user/geo_stuff -file /home/mr_files/mapper.py -mapper "mapper.py"
```

Where mapper.py starts off like...

```
#!./anaconda/anaconda/bin/python
import shapely
from cartopy.io import shapereader
from shapely.geometry import Point
...more stuff
```

And this generates the following error

```
from shapely.geos import lgeos
File "./anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 58, in <module>
_lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'])

File "./anaconda/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 54, in load_dll
libname, fallbacks or []))

OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I include a python package with Hadoop streaming job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job)

Comment: I think this issue is different since geos is a seperate program from python or the Shapely package. Shapely looks for shared c files that are generated when installing geos. The files live in `/usr/local/lib` on my box. I've tried copying that directory to hdfs and adding the following flags to streaming but get the same error. `-files hdfs://namenode:port/user/geos#geos` and `-cmdenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=geos`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy your files from your master node to to all the core nodes on a Hadoop cluster you can do it by running this on your master node (`Key.pem` is the secret key you used to ssh into your master node, you'll have to copy it onto your master node before you run this):

```
#!/bin/bash
nodes=(`hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep Hostname | sed 's/Hostname: //'`)
for workerip in nodes
do
    scp -i Key.pem -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
        -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
           /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c* $workerip:/usr/local/lib/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `libgeos_c.so` shared library for the C API for GEOS in a non-standard location, you can set an environment variable to use that file:

```
export GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libgeos_c.so.1
```

However you many need to ensure that the dependencies are met. E.g. see:

```
ldd /path/to/libgeos_c.so.1
```

See the source for [libgeos.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/libgeos.py) to see how environment variables are used to find the GEOS C API shared libraries.