# Error importing pytz module during hadoop streaming process

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, pytz

I am running a python script on hadoop and It gives the following error

*ImportError: No module named pytz*

When I run the python script on terminal, it executes perfectly. Ideally it should not happen because hadoop uses the same python version and libraries which the system does. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any python package in stream job, it need to be installed on each individual node of the cluster. Other option is to zip the package in a tarball and send it along with `-file` option. Refer to this answer for more details - [How can I include a python package with Hadoop streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job)

Comment: Yes it works and I did that. I just wanted to know why I am getting the error. May be the nodes executing the task may not have pytz installed. I will dig into it and update my findings.