# Why will Hadoop Streaming not import Python packages when executing Hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, package, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

Please see the below Hadoop (3.2.1) error print out, and a summary of my investigation so far:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads():
> subprocess failed with code 1     at
> org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
> at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

From trawling through virtually every possible thread relating to the following Hadoop error print-out, it seems this is thrown for a variety of reasons:

- the most common being that the Python files are not executable,
- or there is a Python error in the code somewhere.

In my case, from spending many hours of testing and by process of elimination, I have figured out that this is being caused whenever I import a specific library such as pandas, nltk, spacy, or whatever the case may be ('os', 'sys', 're' all work fine). I now know this to be the case as I have also discovered the hadoop error logs after a failed job as follows (cannot upload screenshot):

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1596371805267_0001/container_1596371805267_0001_01_000002

cat stderr
```

Returns: ImportError: No module named pandas

Whenever I test the jobs using the following linux command, no errors are thrown. Hence, I know that the libraries are installed in the correct user and there are no syntax errors:

```
cat input_text.csv | python3 mapper.py
```

Once I comment out the 'import pandas' (or any other library except for os, sys and re) at the start of the code, the Hadoop job runs fine. **Does anyone know why Hadoop is not able to pick up these Python libraries?** As I mentioned, Hadoop works fine whenever I do not import these packages - is there anything Python config I need to fix? Any advice is much appreciated, let me know if there is any further info needed. I didn't bother including the mapper in this post as I know for a fact it works fine without importing packages, but fails whenever packages such as pandas, nltk, spacy are imported (regardless whether it is only one or all of these packages).

For further information, please the below:

Python version: Python 3.6.8

Hadoop: 3.2.1 - single machine

Hadoop streaming command (map only):

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.2.1.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
-file $HDUSER_PATH/mapper_clean2.py \
-mapper 'python3 mapper_clean2.py' \
-input $HDFS_PATH/input/combined_tweets_noheader.csv \
-output $HDFS_PATH/output_job1
```

Config files (local machine):

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
</configuration
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you installed these python packages on all worker nodes? Because `'os', 'sys', 're'` is python packages that comes by default. But packages like `pandas, nltk, spacy` is not.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am only running Hadoop on a single node for testing purposes (will eventually go to cluster - hopefully!). I am aware that in a cluster the libraries also need to be installed, but in this case it isn't the issue unfortunately.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811772/10853876